# Getting data from a Google Drive Spreadsheet Cell

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-drive-api

I am attempting to display some data in a HTML document coming from a Google Drive Spreadsheet cell by using the following javascript code:

```
var URL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AhQNAOBkQ63ldFl6N0tDeTFDYWVXeF8yQ0kwdWtoZnc&gid=0&single=true&gid=0&output=txt&range=";
$.ajax(URL + "D2").done(function(result){ document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=result; });
```

This works fine when I have an HTML tag with a "demo" id, but I need the value as a variable so I can display it anywhere in the page and not in a specific HTML element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to specify async:false because otherwise the variable probably won't end up getting set until after you've tried to use it.  Also, for some scope reasons it's easiest to reference a variable in the context of the window (ie `window.variable`).

```
var URL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AhQNAOBkQ63ldFl6N0tDeTFDYWVXeF8yQ0kwdWtoZnc&gid=0&single=true&gid=0&output=txt&range=";

window.variable = "test";

$.ajax({url:URL + "D2",async:false}).done(function(result){ window.variable = result; });

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = window.variable;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Dk4Y/1/

Comment: I may not be clear enough in my previous message. I need to create multiple javascript variables that takes its value from different cells. For instance var1 = "101.43"; var2 = "12", and so on. Then I can just display their values in different places WITHOUT using the ids, just using something like <script>document.write(var2);</script>

Comment: Got it, Samuel, I saw the value it is in the "variable", thanks!

Comment: Just checked it in Internet Explorer and it doesn't show anything from the version 7 up to the 9! Any idea?

Comment: It won't work in Chrome for me now... if you try to visit that Google Docs url that you provided, it says the cell range is invalid.  So there's a deeper problem there that you'll probably have to work out on your own.